# how to restrict price range in google shopping API

Tags: google-api, url-encoding, google-shopping-api

I'm using the Google Shopping API to try to retrieve products that have an "order" of magnitud of a certain number, or approximation to this. For example If I would to select products that are between th $40 - $60 price range : $50 +/- $10. What should I add in the URL search string?

I know I can rank by price like this (according to the API):

```
     GET https://www.googleapis.com/shopping/search/v1/public/products?key=key&country=US&q=%22mp3+player%22%7Cipod&rankBy=price%3Adescending
```

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind, the correct way to do this was using flask and jinja2 along with ajax. One has to be aware of using JSON and how it maps correctly to its equivalent python objects, when using the google shopping API main 'items' objects :

```
"product": {
  "googleId": "9243781955569725518",
  "author": {
    "name": "CompUPlus.com",
    "accountId": "1209120"
  },
  "creationTime": "2010-03-04T09:51:45.000Z",
  "modificationTime": "2010-11-25T09:24:08.000Z",
  "language": "en",
  "country": "US",
  "title": "Logitech Squeezebox Radio, black",
  "description": "Logitech Squeezebox Radio brings a world of free Internet radio subscription
                  services and your personal digital music collection to any space in your home
                  over your Wi-Fi network.",
  "link": "http://www.compuplus.com/Radios/LOGITECH-Squeezebox-Radio-BLK-930-1115160.html",
  "gtin": "00097855063601",
  "gtins": [
   "00097855063601"
  ],
  "brand": "Logitech",
  "mpn": "930-000101",
  "condition": "new",
  "images": [
    { "link": "http://content.etilize.com/300/1014430207.jpg" }
  ]
  "inventories": [
    {
      "channel": "online",
      "availability": "inStock",
      "currency": "usd",
      "price": 183.19
    }
  ],
}
```