# How to restrict results by price in Google products search API

Tags: json, google-api, google-shopping-api, google-product-search

I've been looking over the web for a way to restrict price range on google search shop API but I wasn't able t find any answer. (Let's say I want products between 20 to 40 $)
In the official documentation, it seems to have ne reference to this functionnality (only rank by Price)
Neither [Here](https://developers.google.com/shopping-search/v1/getting_started) nor [Here](https://developers.google.com/shopping-search/v1/reference-request-parameters)

Also,
I've been looking at [this post in stackO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10277291/how-to-restrict-price-range-in-google-shopping-api) but the answer doesnt seem to bring a good solution to the question (he is just stating the technology to use). Is there a way to do so ?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add this to URL of your API call.

```
&restrictBy=price:[20,40]
```

It will return products with prices in between 20 and 40 both inclusive.

```
&restrictBy=price:(20,40]
```

And the above query will return products with prices above 20.

Refer
https://developers.google.com/shopping-search/v1/reference-request-parameters#restricting-products